# How to use Custom Transform in Wrangler?

Tags: cdap, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm trying to use custom transform using a column at Wrangler Plugin.

Is there any documentation where I can find the list of functions to apply the custom transform? Also for a specific case, I wanna replace the value of a column based on IF-ELSE condition (or multiple cases). Is there any way of it?

Comment: For custom cases like this its better to use `Dynamic Spark` plugin that executes user provided spark code written in scala. It can be used to transfrom RDDs with full access to all Spark features.

Answer (score 2):

The custom transform supports JEXL, so you can find a list of functions to apply here: [JEXL syntax](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html). See the [Conditional](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html#Conditional) section of that page for information on how to do an if-else.

Comment: I've tried it with JEXL syntax, initially multiline expression, but later I found that single line expressions are the seemingly only compatible one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the Wrangler directives in a custom transform.  The [GitHub](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler/blob/develop/wrangler-docs/directives/set-column.md) page for the plugin has a comprehensive list with examples.  As Ali Anwar mentioned, directives support JEXL syntax.  For an example have a look at [set-column](https://github.com/data-integrations/wrangler/blob/develop/wrangler-docs/directives/set-column.md) directive.